# Bad query peformance, selecting few fields is 10x slower than selecting many fields

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, hibernate

My team keeps running into a performance problem when using a SQL Server database. First of all, the application is written in Java and utilizes Hibernate. We have some data stored in a database which we can easily and smoothly retrieve, in case we want to select complete objects (like: all or most of the fields in a given table).

This works well, but when we execute a smaller query, it's 10x slower. The most obvious part might be that we just retrieve a small selection of fields (in this example: 3) and use a WHERE-clause with a like in it (which doesn't seem to be the problem when retrieving 84 fields, but when retrieving 3 fields).

Hibernate takes about 7 seconds to finish the simple query compared to about 3,4 seconds with the big one. When running the plain SQL in DbVisualizer, the complex query takes 0.02 seconds for the query and 0.7 seconds to transmit the data. The simple query, run in DbVisualizer, takes a whopping 0.2seconds (10x slower) and then transmits in just about 0.36s (hence, it's less data to be transferred). One might argue that this is still faster than with the big query, but it seems to have some kind of effect on Hibernate performance.

I was joking about it like "Just add additional fields until the damn thing runs fast!", but that doesn't cut it, as both, the fields to be selected and the where clause(s) are going to be user-configured.

The 84-field-query looks like this:

```sql
select
          locateable0_.Un_ID as Un1_37_,
          locateable0_.active as active37_,
          locateable0_.code as code37_,
          locateable0_.name as name37_,
          locateable0_.ClientID as ClientID37_,
          locateable0_.equipmentGroup as equipmen7_37_,
          locateable0_.SupplierContractID as Supplier8_37_,
          locateable0_.orderingCode as ordering9_37_,
          locateable0_.expirationDate as expirat10_37_,
          locateable0_.purchaseDate as purchas11_37_,
          locateable0_.warrantyExpirationAlert as warrant12_37_,
          locateable0_.price as price37_,
          locateable0_.priceUnit as priceUnit37_,
          locateable0_.VatID as VatID37_,
          locateable0_.WEAlertJobID as WEAlert16_37_,
          locateable0_.barcode as barcode37_,
          locateable0_.erpCode as erpCode37_,
          locateable0_.description as descrip19_37_,
          locateable0_.innerWorksheet as innerWo20_37_,
          locateable0_.outerWorksheet as outerWo21_37_,
          locateable0_.ContractorCompanyID as Contrac22_37_,
          locateable0_.ContractorPersonID as Contrac23_37_,
          locateable0_.ManufacturerCompanyID as Manufac24_37_,
          locateable0_.ManufacturerPersonID as Manufac25_37_,
          locateable0_.ServicerCompanyID as Service26_37_,
          locateable0_.ServicerPersonID as Service27_37_,
          locateable0_.BudgetID as BudgetID37_,
          locateable0_.costObjectId as costObj29_37_,
          locateable0_.costKindId as costKindId37_,
          locateable0_.TemplateId as TemplateId37_,
          locateable0_.openingDate as opening32_37_,
          locateable0_.mainClassId as mainCla33_37_,
          locateable0_.pictureId as pictureId37_,
          locateable0_.productType as product35_37_,
          locateable0_.propertiesId as propert36_37_,
          locateable0_.ParentID as ParentID37_,
          locateable0_.accessDomainId as accessD38_37_,
          locateable0_.orderStateType as orderSt39_37_,
          locateable0_.orderEventId as orderEv40_37_,
          locateable0_.locationId as locationId37_,
          locateable0_.siteId as siteId37_,
          locateable0_.buildingId as buildingId37_,
          locateable0_.storeyId as storeyId37_,
          locateable0_.roomId as roomId37_,
          locateable0_.cadObjectId as cadObje46_37_,
          locateable0_.geoLattitude as geoLatt47_37_,
          locateable0_.geoLongitude as geoLong48_37_,
          locateable0_.ratingId as ratingId37_,
          locateable0_.grossArea as grossArea37_,
          locateable0_.grossVolume as grossVo51_37_,
          locateable0_1_.floor as floor99_,
          locateable0_2_.calculatedArea as calculat2_100_,
          locateable0_2_.nominalArea as nominalA3_100_,
          locateable0_2_.categoryId as categoryId100_,
          locateable0_2_.wingId as wingId100_,
          locateable0_2_.areaUnitId as areaUnitId100_,
          locateable0_2_.cleaningArea as cleaning7_100_,
          locateable0_2_.rentableArea as rentable8_100_,
          locateable0_2_.windowSurface as windowSu9_100_,
          locateable0_2_.bottomSurface as bottomS10_100_,
          locateable0_2_.topSurface as topSurface100_,
          locateable0_2_.wallSurface as wallSur12_100_,
          locateable0_2_.floorType as floorType100_,
          locateable0_3_.areaSize as areaSize101_,
          locateable0_3_.areaType as areaType101_,
          locateable0_3_.flooring as flooring101_,
          locateable0_4_.workplaceNumber as workplac2_102_,
          locateable0_4_.workplaceType as workplac3_102_,
          locateable0_4_.usingCompanyId as usingCom4_102_,
          locateable0_5_.quantity as quantity190_,
          locateable0_5_.quantityUnitId as quantity3_190_,
          locateable0_6_.inventoryNumber as inventor2_202_,
          locateable0_7_.area as area233_,
          locateable0_7_.meterValue as meterValue233_,
          locateable0_7_.calibrationFactor as calibrat4_233_,
          locateable0_7_.areaDomainId as areaDoma5_233_,
          locateable0_7_.degreeDayId as degreeDa6_233_,
          locateable0_7_.virtualType as virtualT7_233_,
          locateable0_7_.differenceFactor as differen8_233_,
          locateable0_7_.differenceMasterId as differen9_233_,
          locateable0_7_.virtual as virtual233_,
          locateable0_7_.startDate as startDate233_,
          locateable0_7_.scheduleId as scheduleId233_,
          locateable0_.discriminator as discrimi2_37_
      from
          MNT_Equipments locateable0_
      left outer join
          Storey locateable0_1_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_1_.id
      left outer join
          Room locateable0_2_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_2_.id
      left outer join
          RoomArea locateable0_3_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_3_.id
      left outer join
          Workplace locateable0_4_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_4_.id
      left outer join
          INV_Product locateable0_5_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_5_.id
      left outer join
          MNT_FacilityProduct locateable0_6_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_6_.id
      left outer join
          EN_ResourceMeter locateable0_7_
              on locateable0_.Un_ID=locateable0_7_.id
      left outer join
          DynamicProperties dynamicpro1_
              on locateable0_.propertiesId=dynamicpro1_.id
      left outer join
          KEYWORDSEARCH tags2_
              on dynamicpro1_.id=tags2_.dynamicPropertiesId
      left outer join
          MNT_Clients client3_
              on locateable0_.ClientID=client3_.Un_ID
      where
          (
              locateable0_.accessDomainId is null
              or locateable0_.accessDomainId in       (
                  select
                      uad.domainId
                  from
                      PERM_UserAccessDomain uad
                  join
                      Users u
                          on uad.userId = u.Un_ID
                  where
                      u.UserName = 'wsc'
                      and uad.functionId = 2000
              )
          )
          and locateable0_.discriminator in (
              '17000', '6010', '6020', '6030', '6035', '6040', '6060', '6070', '6080', '18000', '5010', '6000', '6100', '5000', '9000', '14000', '19000'
          )
          and (
              client3_.Un_ID in (
           1012, 1016, 1013, 1014
              )
          )
          and (
              locateable0_.productType not in  (
   18000, 19000
              )
          )
          and locateable0_.active=1
          and locateable0_.productType<>6080
          and (
              upper(tags2_.keyword) like 'B%'
          )
```

The slow 3-field-query looks as follows:

```sql
select
       locateable0_.Un_ID as col_0_0_,
       locateable0_.code as col_1_0_,
       locateable0_.name as col_2_0_
   from
       MNT_Equipments locateable0_
   left outer join
       DynamicProperties dynamicpro1_
           on locateable0_.propertiesId=dynamicpro1_.id
   left outer join
       KEYWORDSEARCH tags2_
           on dynamicpro1_.id=tags2_.dynamicPropertiesId
   left outer join
       MNT_Clients client3_
           on locateable0_.ClientID=client3_.Un_ID
   where
       (
           locateable0_.accessDomainId is null
           or locateable0_.accessDomainId in       (
               select
                   uad.domainId
               from
                   PERM_UserAccessDomain uad
               join
                   Users u
                       on uad.userId = u.Un_ID
               where
                   u.UserName = 'wsc'
                   and uad.functionId = 2000
           )
       )
       and locateable0_.discriminator in (
           '17000', '6010', '6020', '6030', '6035', '6040', '6060', '6070', '6080', '18000', '5010', '6000', '6100', '5000', '9000', '14000', '19000'
       )
       and (
           client3_.Un_ID in (
   1012, 1016, 1013, 1014
           )
       )
       and (
           locateable0_.productType not in  (
   18000, 19000
           )
       )
       and locateable0_.active=1
       and (
           upper(tags2_.keyword) like 'B%'
       )
```

The Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio suggests to add an Index for our requested fields, but doing so doesn't help at all. Especially when keeping in mind that the fields to be queried are going to be user configurable and that hibernate will add a huge bonus on top of the time the query and fetch take.

So, what can we do to increase performance to an acceptable level?

Comment: IN hits performance hard so best use join with comma seperator or something like that

Comment: Without any java code, it's hard to tell what is causing difference between the two queries on java side. Is there any difference in number of entities these queries return? And have you made sure, that hibernate isn't actually initializing ignores fields using additional queries?

Answer (score 2):

I would note that there is a difference in your where clauses, with this in the first:

```
and locateable0_.productType<>6080
```

and missing in the second.

Are there possibly a lot more records with this product type in your database? i.e. does your second query return many more rows than the first?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried it but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the performance.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans in SQL server for both of the queries?  It's the only effective way to figure out where the big time is being spent in your DB structure.